# Oracle Forms : How to make a window/canvas/form the starting one

Tags: oracleforms

I have a school project where I have to make a small database application using Oracle Forms.

I have 4 forms in my application:

1. A login form
2. A main form
3. A form that is displayed after the new button is pressed on the main form
4. Another form that is displayed after the edit button is pressed on the main form.

I've created the forms in the mentioned way.

When I start the application, I want the login form to be the starting form. Now what starts first is the edit form (the last one created).

How can I manage that?

Thank you.

Comment: how do you start the application?

Answer (score 2):

The form loads that canvas first which holds the first data block in the Object Navigator. So make sure that your login form block is first on the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the "First Navigation Data Block" in the Property Palette for the form to the desired block on the login form and it will display that first, overriding the first block in the other answer.